# PedWait block in Anylogic assistance

Tags: anylogic

i am new in using Anylogic , and i see in the PedWait block , Delay end on free function call , what does that mean and what is the difference between choosing it and the on delay time expiry  ?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community :) Simple questions like are often covered in the AnyLogic help as well, check it out: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/pedestrian-library/pedwait.html#pedwait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the free function call is used in case you want to use something different than a time delay to allow the pedestrian to continue to the next block.

For example, a pedestrian can wait until a resource is available... since you don't know if the resource is going to be available in an exact amount of time, you can't use a time delay, so you use a free function call.

And when the resource becomes available, you can free the pedestrian by doing pedWait.free(ped)